# WPF: Get Tabtitle from Content (in template)

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I'm trying to display the Title of an Tabitem in his contentpresenter. Is there a possibility to get this name?

For example in the Tabcontrol Template something like

```
<Label>
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContentHeader" Grid.Row="1" />
</Label>
```

to display the name of the current tab in label.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, (e.g. is the label part of a control template or separate?), but this displays tabControl1's current TabItem's name in a label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=tabControl1,Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, the label is part of a control template. So I think this won't work. But you helped me to an idea that worked:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to arx for the right direction ;)
EDIT: And also thanks to John

```
   <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem.Header}" />
```